# VBScript get SNMP OID values

Tags: vbscript, snmp, oid

I'm trying to use access SNMP via VBScript to access a few OID values as it's a climate monitor which has figures for temperature, humidity and airflow.  I know which OID's I need to use but cannot find any script or piece of code which effectively connects and pulls out out this information.

Has anyone got anything that fits the bill?

I tried using this code but keep getting an error: `ActiveX component can't create object: 'Scripting.SNMPManager'`

```
Set oSNMPManager = CreateObject("Scripting.SNMPManager")

oSNMPManager.Agent = "unitip"
oSNMPManager.Community = "public"


'Add Variable objects to Variables collection
Call oSNMPManager.Variables.Add( "1.3.6.1.4.1.17373.2.2.1.6.1" )

Result = oSNMPManager.Get( ErrorIndex )
WScript.Echo "Get result: " & Result
If Result = 10 Then
WScript.Echo "ErrorIndex: " & ErrorIndex
End If

'Display properties of all Variable objects
WScript.Echo "OID, Type, Value"
For Each SNMPVariable in oSNMPManager.Variables
WScript.Echo SNMPVariable.OID & ", " & SNMPVariable.Type & ", " & SNMPVariable.Value
next

'Remove all Variable objects from the Variables collection
oSNMPManager.Variables.RemoveAll
```

Comment: Where did you find "Scripting.SNMPManager?" The error message is telling you that component doesn't exist, essentially.

Answer (score -1):

```
Set objSnmpManager  = CreateObject( "AxNetwork.SnmpManager" )
Set objConstants    = CreateObject( "AxNetwork.NwConstants" )
```

' A license key is required to unlock this component after the trial period has expired.
' Call 'Activate' with a valid license key as its first parameter. Second parameter determines whether to save the license key permanently 
' to the registry (True, so you need to call Activate only once), or not to store the key permanently (False, so you need to call Activate
' every time the component is created). For details, see manual, chapter "Product Activation".
'
' objSnmpManager.Activate "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX", False

Comment: Why did you assume the OP was using the ActiveXperts compinent? If they are not, your response is useless and adds nothing.